# Registration with verification

Tags: magento2, registration

I would like that when a user registers on my site they have to go through a filter in which the administrator of the page must accept or deny the registration.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2 by default only comes with user e-mail verification.

So you'll either have to built the approval functionality yourself or use a 3rd party plugin like https://marketplace.magento.com/eh-customer-approve.html.

**Edit:** If you're just getting started on module development you can check out the official Magento 2.2.x documentation here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html

There are also some module example codes available here: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples

Comment: And how can I build an approval functionality? I'm a bit noob in Magento and programation so I'm lost on this "new world"....

Comment: See updated answer. If you're just getting started then the documentation is your best friend.